# Most efficient method to readprocessmemory for neighbouring addresses?

Tags: c#, .net

I am reading addresses in memory with the below code.  It occurred to me that I may be doing this very inefficiently as I am making individual calls for every address despite all of the addresses being neighbours to each other (1 byte along).

```
    [DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "ReadProcessMemory")]
    private static extern byte ReadProcessMemoryByte(int Handle, int Address, ref byte Value, int Size, ref int BytesRead);
```

The function looks something like:

```
pseudo: 
       For loop: 
       read memory address (base address offset)
       add result to array
       addressoffset++
```

So say I have 3 addresses, I would be making 3 separate calls.  Is there a way to make just 1 call and then do so internal logic to split the result into 3 separate data segments, if you know what I mean?  Like instead of reading byte by byte, read 4 bytes at once then split them up before adding to the array?

The reason I am asking this is that my program takes forever to go through the iterations, sometimes having to read up to 40,000 addresses which takes 3 minutes. If I could do what I am asking, then maybe I could cut it down under a minute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.readprocessmemory, the method signature should be like:

```
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  static extern bool ReadProcessMemory( 
    IntPtr hProcess, 
    IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
    [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, 
    int dwSize, 
    out int lpNumberOfBytesRead
   );
```

Currently, since you only have a single `byte` for `lpBuffer`/`Value`, you are only reading one byte at a time.  You can read many more (maybe all of the bytes you intend to read, or broken up into, say, 1024 byte chunks) by making that a `byte[]` and passing a `Size` larger than 1.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Lets say I have 150 bytes in neighbouring addresses, could I make the length 150 then process the array after with iterations, would that make much difference to the speed do you think rather than 150 seperate calls?

Comment: significantly faster, due to not thunking out to unmanaged code.

Comment: So 40,000 calls become 200 (previously reading up to 200 addresses 200 times) - I feel so stupid right now..